# Mushroom grilled sandwich in Budapest

Tags: restaurants, recommendations, hungary, budapest

I was in Győr a few years back and had an **amazing** grilled sandwich with sautéd mushrooms and cheese. I am asking this here, because it looked like it was a Hungarian specialty.

Being in Budapest for a few days, I haven't been able to find a restaurant that serves this, by looking at menus outside tourist restaurants. Is it only served in Győr? Are there places in Budapest that also make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small, centrally located restaurant by the name of [Úri Cipő – Kaptafa](https://linktr.ee/kaptafabar) that serves a grilled cheese sandwich with mushrooms and chèvre.  There are photos of it on the restaurant's [menu](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fcslEEkFJPxQH1TpWw_bHCv3FaxbarJy/view) and [Instagram channel](https://www.instagram.com/p/CgEocQquPN-/).  I don't know how it compares to what you ate in Győr, but I can attest that everything we had in this restaurant was delicious.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if it's the same as in Győr (I suspect you're talking about Arrabona Ételbár's speciality), but you should be fine everywhere [where they serve "melegszendvics"](https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&near=Budapest&nearGeoId=72057594040982579&q=melegszendvics).

Personally I'd go with [Cserpes Tejivó](http://www.cserpestejivo.hu/menu.php), because they seem to have grilled mushroom sandwiches, they have a few locations around the city (in Sütő utca, at Corvin, in Allee and in MOM Sport) and a friend of mine likes the place.